# google matrix not returning value in miles?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ive been trying to get google matrix to return the response in miles. The api seems to return the text as miles but the value as KM. Am I missing something? My code is below. I have also attacked a screenshot of the response
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlHl1.png

```
function calculateDistances() {
  var postcode= $('#postcode-check').val();
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: ['NW6 1HR'],
    destinations: [postcode],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
  }, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the [documented behavior](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_results).

**Distance Matrix Results**

> distance: The total distance of this route, **expressed in meters (value)** and as text. **The textual value is formatted according to the unitSystem specified in the request (or in metric, if no preference was supplied).**

You can convert the `value` in meters to the unit system you prefer.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. I misinterpreted the Unit Systems documentation: _units - Specifies the unit system to use when expressing distance as __text__...Unit Systems - Note: The distance fields also contain values which are always expressed in meters._ I didn't realize that the value is always in meters. [Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#unit_systems)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with Google Maps the `value` is *always* in meters, probably for standardization reasons. Therefore, the units designation refers only to the *text* returned, and not the physical distance.

**Solutions**

1. Divide meters by 1609.34.
2. Use `parseFloat(value.replace(' mi',''))`, though this will not be as accurate.